# Keeping NSManagedObject not being faulted when using with closures?

Tags: swift, core-data, closures, nsmanagedobject

How to force `NSManagedObject` not to be faulted when using it inside closures/blocks?

For example:

```
func doSomething() {

    // 1. Create NSManagedObject
    var managedObject: MyManagedObject = … // create new NSManagedObject

    // 2. Do an api call
    api.request() { error in

       print(managedObject) // <MyManagedObject: 0x78d676b0> ... ; data: <fault>)

       // 3. save some values into managedObject
       managedObject.property1 = ...

       // Crash: CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0x7b0e2670...
    }
}
```

**Updated:**

If I keep reference of the managedObject outside the method, the object is not being faulted. Everything works.

Comment: Please post the error and the complete line causing the crash.

Comment: Use `context.perform { ... }` or `context.performAndWait { ... }` to ensure that  the Core Data operations are executed on the right queue.

Comment: @shallowThought the object is faulted, the data is removed. Martin R  everything is happening on the same thread.

Comment: Create your in`api.request() {...`. Martins advice is also valuable as a general best practice.

Comment: It is not an option to create inside the closure.

Comment: Post more code. Otherwize impossible to help.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I am not sure what to post more. Are you familiar with faulting? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html

Comment: Instead of passing the managedObject to the closure, use the managedObjectID. Fetch that object inside the closure and then perform the operation. The managedObject is not thread safe and managedObjectID supports thread safety.